# Tikz will not load properly on fresh TexLive 2021 Mac install

Tags: tikz-pgf

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Output in console:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-10-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty:13: Argumen
t of \next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgf.sty}
                                 
? 
Runaway argument?
pgf.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty:13: Paragra
ph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.13 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgf.sty}
                                 
? 
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty:13: Too man
y }'s.
<recently read> }
                 
l.13 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgf.sty}
                                 
? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
 (/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathoperations.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathtrig.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathrnd.code.tex))
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathbase.code.tex)))
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code
.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
) (/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)

(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.
tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.co
de.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.cod
e.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)))
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty:30: Undefin
ed control sequence.
l.30 \usepgfmodule
                  {shapes,plot}
? 

/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty:30: LaTeX E
rror: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.30 \usepgfmodule{s
                    hapes,plot}
? 

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-
0-65.sty:12: Argument of \next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty}
                                                  
? 
Runaway argument?
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-
0-65.sty:12: Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.12 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty}
                                                  
? 
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-
0-65.sty:12: Too many }'s.
<recently read> }
                 
l.12 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty}
                                                  
? 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-
1-18.sty:12: Argument of \next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty}
                                                  
? 
Runaway argument?
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-
1-18.sty:12: Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.12 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty}
                                                  
? 
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-
1-18.sty:12: Too many }'s.
<recently read> }
                 
l.12 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty}
                                                  
? 
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathoperations.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathtrig.code.tex)
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathrnd.code.tex))
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathbase.code.tex))))
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))

(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.code.tex
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.cod
e.tex)
/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.code.tex:894: Unde
fined control sequence.
l.894 \pgfsetsnakesegmenttransformation
                                       {\pgf@snake@mirror\pgf@snake@raise}
? 
(/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarytikztopaths.code
.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./Untitled.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map

}]
(./Untitled.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on Untitled.pdf (1 page, 12543 bytes).
SyncTeX written on Untitled.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Untitled.log.
```

This is a completely fresh and up to date TeXLive 2021 with all available packages installed and updated (installed and updated less than an hour ago). Running on OS X Monterey 12.0.1 fully updated. I am at a loss.

Comment: The problem may be that you mix files from different sources. Compare `/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex` to `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty`. You seem to have two TeX installations. One under `/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/` and another one under `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/`. You may want to try to remove the one under `/Users/jonb/Library/texmf/` (by renaming the directory, say).

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. Not sure how I had both (probably from a very ancient pre-2016 install), but getting rid of the user texmf did the trick.