# compile error "! Argument of \next has an extra }." when using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

This has been happening to me for a number of years now but I've finally gotten sick of it and would like a solution that gets rid of it.

When I use the tikz package and compile using pdflatex, I get an error message

```
! Argument of \next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 \ProvidesPackageRCS{pgf.sty}
```

The error isn't fatal, because if I keep hitting "enter" eventually it'll get past the issue and the rest compiles fine.  But I miss being able to just type "pdflatex [file] + enter" and have it go without any more input from me.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

There's clearly some mismatched } somewhere: But where? Where do I need to go to add or delete a brace so that this goes away?

Comment: Could be a version conflict (i.e. old package files mixed with new) ... can you upload the `.log` file here?

Comment: Your document example works fine! No Errors, no Warnings, no Bad Boxes. Your errors is caused by something not present in it.

Comment: Please provide the log from your compilation of this MWE.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/621130/2388

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike, that link gave me the clue I needed to find the culprit.  Solved!